# jqm 1.3.2 and jquery 1.9.1 upgrades from jqm 1.0.1 and jquery 1.6.4 breaks my popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to upgrade an old jquery mobile site running on 1.0.1 and jquery 1.6.4 version to  the latest version and have problems replacing certain jquery sections  that work on a select popup button. 
The following is the HTML generated in the older version

```
                <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop in" style="top: 30px; right: 30px;">
                    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a">

                <h1 class="ui-title">Search Results</h1>

                <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" href="#" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" title="Close" data-theme="a" style="display: none;">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span>
                </span>
                </a>

                    </div>
                    <ul id="action_menu-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="action_menu-button" data-theme="a">
                        <li class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-active" data-icon="false" data-option-index="0" role="option" tabindex="0" data-theme="a" aria-selected="true">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#">Search Results</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="false" data-option-index="1" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-theme="a" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#">Home</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="false" data-option-index="2" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-theme="a" aria-selected="false">
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#">Email</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And the follwoing is the HTML generated by my current code

```
                <div id="action_menu-listbox-screen" class="ui-popup-screen in"></div>
                <div id="action_menu-listbox-popup" class="ui-popup-container ui-popup-active" style="max-width: 1564px; top: 30.0001px; left: 14px;" tabindex="0">
                    <div id="action_menu-listbox" class="ui-selectmenu ui-popup ui-body-a ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all">
                        <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a">

                <h1 class="ui-title">Search Results</h1>

                        </div>
                        <ul id="action_menu-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="action_menu-button" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b">
                            <li class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-first-child" data-option-index="0" data-icon="false" data-placeholder="true" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" aria-selected="false">
                                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#" tabindex="-1">Search Results</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-a" data-option-index="1" data-icon="false" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" aria-selected="false">
                                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#" tabindex="-1">Home</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-a" data-option-index="2" data-icon="false" role="option" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" aria-selected="false">
                                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="#" tabindex="-1">Email</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

I have not changed the older code except the javascript that has a live method which I am struggling to completely understand and replace. which is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                   $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme= "c";
                       $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'none';
                        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
                        $.extend(  $.mobile , { 
                              ajaxFormsEnabled : false,
                              ajaxLinksEnabled : false,
                                  ajaxEnabled:false,
                                  // loadingMessage: false
                         });
                  });
                </script>

        <script src="</jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <%--Script added by B37914 for CR43399 on 7th March,2012--%>
        <script src="/m_alert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/m_common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>
            var mobileMainViewUrl = 'http;//www.yahoo.com';
            var urlForEmailAction = document.location.href;

             $('#header-logo').click(function(){alert("this is the header alert");});

            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                  $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'none';        
            });

            **
```

> **$("select[id='action_menu']").live("change",actionHandler);**

**

```
            $(document).ready(function(){       
                if($("li[class*='ui-btn-icon-right']")!=null){
                    $("li[class*='ui-btn-icon-right']").each(function(ind,elm){
                        var anch=$(this).find("a[class*='ui-link-inherit']");
                        var arrowIcn=$(elm).find("span[class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow']");
                        if(anch !=null && arrowIcn!=null){
                            $(arrowIcn).appendTo(anch);
                        }
                    });
                    }
            });

            function showActionMenu(assetId,assetType){

                var language=document.getElementById("m_lang").value;
                var pageTitle = $('title').html();
                pageTitle = pageTitle.replace("&amp;","and");
                pageTitle = pageTitle.replace("amp;","");
                pageTitle = pageTitle.replace("&","and");
                //changed by b36050 for cr-48634 on 17 jan 2013
                callActionButton('action_menu',pageTitle,urlForEmailAction,true,assetId,assetType,deleteFavorite,language);

                }

        </script>
```

Please check the code that generates these two HTML's and the .js file at http://jsfiddle.net/hgafoor/85qy3/

I have tried various options but I am not able to somehow get the value of the options when i use click. I have tried using #action_menu-menu as a selector and have tried bind and delegate I do not understand why in the newer version the id which is action_menu is added as the primary div to generate the popup instead of ui-selectmenu. I have been stuck on this for a while now and would be a great reliever if someone can help me out with this

Comment: Do you need some new functionality? If not, I recommend simply not upgrading.

Comment: Global settings `mobileinit` should be loaded after jQ and before jQM. Use `.on` instead of `.live`, and don't use `.ready()` in jQM, use `pageinit` or other jQM events.

Comment: I suppose this is a typo? `<script src="</jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Like this is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/85qy3/1/, is what are you looking for?

Comment: @Blazemonger: I need to upgrade, moving to a newer search engine which does not support the older versions.

Comment: @Omar:, I am trying to use .on but how do I replace "select[id='action_menu']" I get an undefined object when I use #action_menu-menu. What I do not understand is why action_menu comes in as the name of the div that holds the popup i.e. action_menu-listbox where is this coming from ? and how do I access the option object.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward: there seems to be no action on the button click on the code you provided.

Comment: @MelanciaUK : just trying to reference jquery mobile version 1.0.1 saved on my local machine.

Comment: The right arrow button is working, can you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward the right arrow button needs to show me a pop-up with options and when I click on the option it needs to perform the action defined in the  m_common.js file in the first case needs to redirect to HOME url which for now I have set to yahoo.com  which is this var- mobileMainViewUrl

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/85qy3/2/

Comment: @Omar that works with an alert does not work with the actionHandler function

Comment: I dont know what `actionHandler()` does. I made a cleaner version of your demo, check it and tell me what you want to achieve exactly. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nheGE/

Comment: I just noticed actionHandler is basically a variable that is defined  like                                                                var actionHandler =function(event,ui){
var action = "";                                                                  if($(this).val()=="home"){
window.location.href = mobileMainViewUrl; 
 }                                                                  }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nheGE/ like this?

Comment: @Omar Why does this code not trigger the URL? and can you tell me in simple terms why one would use actionHandler as a variable instead of defining directly as a function, its in the code I am trying to modify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38733/discussion-between-omar-and-yaba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me  was fairly a simple solution credits : @Omar

Some points I learned :
1. Need to load the actionHandler function before actually calling it(which is a no brainer, but me being a beginner had a hard time wrapping my head around). 
2.The mobileinit function need to be called before loading the JQM and other .js files. 
3. the call to the actionHandler needs to be placed in the ready() for it to trigger the action.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var mobileMainViewUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        var urlForEmailAction = document.location.href;
        var deleteFavorite = "";

         $('select').on('change', actionHandler);
});
```

Comment: Replace `.ready()` with `pageinit`. The first shouldn't be used in JQM ;)